# The wrong "items" funciton is being selected by lazy row unless i specifically import "import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items"

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

So im trying to follow an example from jetpack compose for lazyrows

When creating the lazy row object unless i specify this import:
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items

the items function inside the lazyrow function throws this error:
Type mismatch: inferred type is List<DrawableStringPair> but Int was expected

I believe its going to a different function based on the inputs, but im trying to figure out why the import statement above fixes it.
All of the "items" functions are defined within the same file "LazyDsl.kt"

I guess my question is, how does the import above specify that its
This function:

```
inline fun <T> LazyListScope.items(
    items: List<T>,
    noinline key: ((item: T) -> Any)? = null,
    noinline contentType: (item: T) -> Any? = { null },
    crossinline itemContent: @Composable LazyItemScope.(item: T) -> Unit
) = items(
```

and not this one:

```
fun items(
    count: Int,
    key: ((index: Int) -> Any)? = null,
    contentType: (index: Int) -> Any? = { null },
    itemContent: @Composable LazyItemScope.(index: Int) -> Unit
) {
    error("The method is not implemented")
}
```

Data:

```
private val alignYourBodyData = listOf(
    R.drawable.ab1_inversions to R.string.ab1_inversions,
    R.drawable.ab2_quick_yoga to R.string.ab2_quick_yoga,
    R.drawable.ab3_stretching to R.string.ab3_stretching,
    R.drawable.ab4_tabata to R.string.ab4_tabata,
    R.drawable.ab5_hiit to R.string.ab5_hiit,
    R.drawable.ab6_pre_natal_yoga to R.string.ab6_pre_natal_yoga
).map { DrawableStringPair(it.first, it.second) }
```

Function causing problems:

```
@Composable
fun AlignYourBodyRow(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    LazyRow(
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        items(alignYourBodyData) { item ->
            AlignYourBodyElement(item.drawable, item.text)
        }
    }
}
```

Composable function:

```
@Composable
fun AlignYourBodyElement(
    @DrawableRes drawable: Int,
    @StringRes text: Int,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(drawable),
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(88.dp)
                .clip(CircleShape)
        )
        Text(
            text = stringResource(text),
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h3,
            modifier = Modifier.paddingFromBaseline(
                top = 24.dp, bottom = 8.dp
            )
        )
    }
}
```

import that fixes everything:
`import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items`

Comment: So is that second `items` method your top level method (i.e., one the same package)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that "All of the `items` functions are defined within the same file *LazyDsl.kt*". The difference is that the function with `count` argument is **member function** of `LazyListScope`, while the other function with `items` argument is **extension function** of `LazyListScope`.

And by design, you don't need import to call member function of a class, but you need one to call extension function.

To the second question, "How does the import above specify that its this function and not the other one?" - it does not. The import only enables you to call the extension function (all the extension functions called `items`). The one with `count` argument is available by default. The correct one is then chosen automatically based on the arguments you provide.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jan this explains it perfectly

Answer (score 5):

Remove the `items(alignYourBodyData) {...}` code and its import, and try to type it again yourself!
Then you'll be shown auto-suggestion dialog like this and you can select your function:

[image: video]

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment, ill do this in the future i just wasn't sure why we needed the import but the answer below makes sense